# Efficient string Match with SQL and Python

Tags: python, psycopg2, psql, string-matching

I want to know what is the best approach for a String Match with Python and a PSQL database. My db contains pubs names and zip codes. I want check if there are observations refering to the same pub but spelled differently by mistake.

Conceptually, I was thinking of looping through all the names and, for each other row in the same zip code, obtain a string similarity metric using [strsim](https://pypi.org/project/strsim/). If this metric is above a threshold, I insert it into another SQL table which stores the match candidates.

I think I am being inefficient. In "pseudo-code", having pub_table, candidates_table and using the JaroWinkler function, I mean to do something like:

```
from similarity.jarowinkler import JaroWinkler
jarowinkler = JaroWinkler()

cursor = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT name, zip from pub_table")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for r in rows:
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM pub_tables WHERE zip = %s", (r[1],))
    search = cur.fetchall()

    for pub in search:
        if jarowinkler.similarity(r[0], pub[0]) > threshold:
             insertion = ("INSERT INTO candidates_table (name1, name2, zip) 
                          VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
             cur.execute(insertion, (r[0], pub[0], zip))

cursor.close ()
conn.commit ()
conn.close ()
```

I am sorry if am not being clear (novice here). Any guidance for string matching using PSQL and Python will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code for `distance_metric` ?

Comment: Please consider it as a given function (I am editing with a Jaro-Winkler for the sake of completeness). My struggle is with the pairing process which I think is being inefficient. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Just in case you're not limited to the Jaro-Winkler distance - PostgreSQL has built-in support for Levenshtein distance in its `fuzzystrmatch` module.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene! I am planning to try it with several string distance metrics. Any comments or guiance regarding best practice for string matching in SQL you may have will be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the SELECT queries are on the same `pub_tables` table. And the inner loop with the second query on zip-match repeats for every row of `pub_tables`. You could directly get the zip equality comparison in one query by doing an INNER JOIN of `pub_tables` with itself.

```sql
SELECT p1.name, p2.name, p1.zip
FROM   pub_table p1,
       pub_table p2
WHERE  p1.zip = p2.zip
AND    p1.name != p2.name  -- this line assumes your original pub_table
                           -- has unique names for each "same pub in same zip"
                           -- and prevents the entries from matching with themselves.
```

That would reduce your code to just the outer query & inner check + insert, without needing a second query:

```
cur.execute("<my query as above>")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for r in rows:
    # r[0] and r[1] are the names. r[2] is the zip code
    if jarowinkler.similarity(r[0], r[1]) > threshold:
         insertion = ("INSERT INTO candidates_table (name1, name2, zip) 
                      VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
         # since r already a tuple with the columns in the right order,
         # you can replace the `(r[0], r[1], r[2])` below with just `r`
         cur.execute(insertion, (r[0], r[1], r[2]))
         # or ...
         cur.execute(insertion, r)
```

Another change: The `insertion` string is always the same, so you can move that to before the `for` loop and only keep the parameterised `cur.execute(insertion, r)` inside the loop. Otherwise, you're just redefining the same static string over and over.

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly useful for improving the efficiency. Do you know where I can find material on this topic using SQL and Python? Thanks again

Comment: Depends on which DB and API you're using. The optimisations I mentioned above would apply to any DB + Programming language combo. Consider learning more about DB's and SQL first. How to use SQL results smartly with your code will follow. If you look at the actual optimisation I provided, it's mostly your SQL I optimised, not your Python :-) The Python changes were an after-effect of the SQL changes. You could even completely swap out the fuzzy matching-algo and it would change nothing in the SQL parts. (Unless you could do the fuzzy matching directly in SQL.)